# SF 4.4 - XXXController::getParameter() method is missing a parameter bag to work properly

Tags: php, symfony

### Issue :

I recently encountered a blocking issue in my Symfony Project. I just upgraded from 3.4 to 4.4. I followed the guidelines and replaced all deprecated notices.

I have a huge and dirty controller for a side feature.

As written in SF doc I replaced :

```
class XXXController extends Controller
```

by

```
class XXXController extends AbstractController
```

In my logic the function **getParameter()** from *src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php* is called.

```
   protected function getParameter(string $name)
{
    if (!$this->container->has('parameter_bag')) {
        throw new ServiceNotFoundException('parameter_bag.', null, null, [], sprintf('The "%s::getParameter()" method is missing a parameter bag to work properly. Did you forget to register your controller as a service subscriber? This can be fixed either by using autoconfiguration or by manually wiring a "parameter_bag" in the service locator passed to the controller.', static::class));
    }

    return $this->container->get('parameter_bag')->get($name);
}
```

But I always fall in the 'if' condition.

### I tried :

Auto-wiring declaration in my service.yml like :

```
services:
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
```

To overwrite the **getParameters()** in my controller.

To declare my controller has a service but it began to get really messy because the targeted method is more than 1k lines long.

I tried to bind it as a common argument in service.yml

### Actual Work Around

Now my only solution is to keep extending the old **Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller** for every controller where I need to call getParameter() on the container.

Is there an easy way for injecting *Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag* in my targeted controller ? Am I missing something obvious ?

### EDIT :

- When I try

php bin/console debug:container parameter_bag

I got :

```
    Information for Service "parameter_bag"
=======================================

 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       parameter_bag
  Class            Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ContainerBag
  Tags             -
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        no
  Autoconfigured   no
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------


 ! [NOTE] The "parameter_bag" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled.
```

*There is an issue with the notice about the service been removed from container ? I can't find why tho.*

- When i try :

```
bin/console debug:container XXXController
```

I got :

```
Information for Service "xxx_controller"
=========================================

 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------
  Service ID       xxx_controller
  Class            AppBundle\Controller\Backend\XXXController
  Tags             controller.service_arguments
                   container.service_subscriber
  Calls            setContainer
  Public           yes
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes
```

I declared it in my *service.yml*

```
xxx_controller:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\Backend\XXXController
    arguments:
        - $parameterBag : '@parameter_bag'
    public: true
```

**__construct()** method in *XXXController*

```
 /**
     * @var ParameterBag
     */
    private $parameterBag;

    public function __construct(ParameterBag $parameterBag) {
        $this->parameterBag = $parameterBag;
    }
```

But using this solution I always get the error :

```
 XXXController has required constructor arguments and does not exist in the container. Did you forget to define the controller as a service?
```

Am I stuck in a loop ? Defining in the constructor method and *service.yml* is not enought ? How can I provide the ParameterBag ?

*NB :*

- *It's an edit method with an {id} as route param*
- *I already cleanned cache multiple times & did a composer_update & checked for issues between dependencies on packagist.*

Comment: Try to run `php bin/console cache:clear` (it can be useful if you jumped from one version symfony to another) and check what does `php bin/console debug:container parameter_bag`. If nothing - assume that you have symfony 4.4 in your composer.json file and run `composer update`

Comment: could you provide us an example of your controller, specially if the controller has a constructor.

Comment: Does bin/console debug:container XXXController show your controller defined as a service?  Do you also have the resource lines in your services.yml?  Because it looks like your controllers are not being picked up as services.

Comment: I just edited the post regarding what you asked, thanks for your help

Comment: Change xxx_controller to the fully qualified controller class name in your service.yml file.  There are actually two services being generated here.  One called xxx_controller which you are explicitly defining and another called XXXController which is defined by autowire and is being used by the routing system.  Assuming you actually have the standard App\ resource lines in your services.yml file then you should be able to comment out xxx_controller completely.  But just changing the service id to the class name should help.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you so much ! Changing the service name to the fully qualified name solved the problem. I thought it was just related to alias, my bad.  You can make an answer no pb